# R Raster Stack gap filling using next and previous layers

Tags: r, gis, raster

I have landsat 8 scenes NDVI for a year about 10 images. I remove clouds and then try to fill gaps using approxNA.

Problem: It works fine on small rasters but it takes about 1hr to finish on whole landsat scenes and then it gives error. Is there an alternate on how to proceed. Each scene has about 60million cells so 10 files in stack would be 600million cells. if i check values of x1 it shows values up to first 47-48million cells and after that it just says something like "vector of length zero".

Following is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

#set working directory
setwd("E:/Test/")

#Read and stack files
f <- list.files(path = "E:/Test/", pattern = "NDVI*\\.tif$")
s <- stack(f)

x <- approxNA(s, rule=1, z=c(1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,14,15))
```

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting?  You can also try `terra::approximate `

Comment: Thanks Robert for responding. I fixed the error by increasing the memory allocated by R through rasteroptions(). Could you please explain the difference between rule 1 and rule 2 of above function